# A question of straight lines

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

If the straight lines $x+y-2=0$, $2x-y+1=0$ and $px+qy-r=0$ are concurrent, then what is the slope of the member of family of lines $2px+3qy+4r=0$ which is farthest from origin?

I wrote the coefficients of the variables of the given lines in a determinant, equated it to $0$ and got $p+5q-3r=0$. Then, I substituted $r$ in the equation of the family of lines. What do I do next? How to find the line farthest from the origin?

Comment: Actually, if I'm understanding correctly, for the lines to be concurrent, the three lines should meet, so that the determinant should be _non-zero_ .

Comment: No, the condition for three lines to be concurrent is that the determinant should be zero.

Comment: The lines meet at $(1/3,5/3)$. That gives an equation linking $p$, $q$, and $r$. Now look up the distance from a point (in this case the origin) to a line. To get rid of one of the variables, note that multiplying $p,q,r$ by a constant does not change the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the distance formula for the distance between a line and a plane to get
$$d=\frac{r}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}$$
Clearly r=$\frac{p+5q}{3}$

Substitute in the above equation to get
$$d=\frac{\frac{p+5q}{3}}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}$$
Dividing numerator and denominator by p,we get d in terms of q/p=$\lambda$. Now q/p is the slope of the line. Differentiate d w.r.t $\lambda$ and equate it to 0 to find the maximum value of the slope.